# Download canvas content feature not working

Tags: javascript, canvas

i've tried several ways to download the elements i have inside the canvas as one image but none of them worked, here are the 2 last codes i tried

HTML :

```
<canvas id="canvas"  style= "border:3px solid #000000"></canvas>
<input id="download" class="rc" type="button" value="Download">
```

Javascript:

```
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        canvas.width = 400;
        canvas.height = 400;
```

Method 1 :

```
document.getElementById('download').addEventListener('click', function() {
        
    // IE/Edge
    if(window.navigator.msSaveBlob){
            window.navigator.msSaveBlob(canvas.msToBlob(),"horse.png");
    }else{
        
           const a = document.createElement("a");
           document.body.appendChild(a);
           a.href = canvas.toDataURL();
           a.download = "horse.png"
           a.click();
           document.body.removeChild(a);

      }
```

Method 1 works for internet explorer only.

Method 2 :

```
        const horseimg = canvas.toDataURL();
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = horseimg ;
        link.download = 'horse.png';
        link.click();
```

Comment: May the browser just protect users from clicking the link directly from the code? Did you try to simply put that link to the page and let user click it himself?

Comment: @Leonid How can i do so?

Comment: Anyone got an idea? i've tried everything still nothing. :(